# Xamarin Forms layout does not fit on smaller screen

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been given an existing Xamarin Forms project that works as expected on one device and I'm trying to correct some issues with a screen layout when running the project on another device with a slightly smaller screen. On the smaller device, some items at the top and bottom of the screen are inaccessible (SKU/PO number, Save and Continue button, and Count). My goal is to have the layout scale with the screen size so it works on both devices. I would like to avoid using a scrollview if possible. I am new to Xamarin Forms but I have some experience working with Xamarin Android. Here are some screenshots of the layout when displayed on both devices [Correct display on existing device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBT3s.png) [Incorrect display on new device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI5pt.png)

And here is the layout.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/ReceivingBaseViewStyle.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/BaseLotViewStyle.xaml" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <!--<ScrollView>-->
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ScannerGridStyle}"
                RowSpacing="0"
                ColumnSpacing="0"
              >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" 
                            Style="{StaticResource BasePageIdRowStyle}">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="9" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0"
                            Text="{Binding Model.AdvanceShipNoticeIdentifier, StringFormat={x:Static resources:Labels.Global_AsnNumber_Template}}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource AsnIdRowLabelStyle}"
                            AutomationId="AsnNumber" />
                    <Image Grid.Column="1" 
                            Style="{StaticResource SeparatorDarkStyle}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2"
                            Text="{Binding Model.PurchaseOrderNumber, StringFormat={x:Static resources:Labels.Global_PoNumber_Template}}" 
                            Style="{StaticResource PoIdRowLabelStyle}"
                            AutomationId="PoNumber" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" 
                            Style="{StaticResource BasePageTitleWithIdRowStyle}">
                <Label Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_SelectLot}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource BasePageTitleLabelStyle}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="2"
                            Style="{StaticResource SingleRowHighlightedStyle}">
                <controls:HintLabel Text="{Binding Model.ItemSku, StringFormat={x:Static resources:Labels.Global_SkuNumber_Template}}"
                        Style="{StaticResource HighlightedRowValueStyle}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="3"
                            Spacing="0"
                            Style="{StaticResource DescriptionRowStyle}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label x:Name="DescriptionTitle"
                            Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.Global_Description_Title}"
                            Style="{StaticResource DefaultLabelStyle}" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <controls:HintLabel x:Name="DescriptionText"
                            Text="{Binding Model.ItemDescription}"
                            Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextStyle}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="4"
                            Style="{StaticResource SeparatorRowStyle}">
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource SeparatorContentStyle}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="5"
                            Style="{StaticResource LotInputRowStyle}">

                <templates:CustomToggle LeftState="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsNewLotCreating, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                                        ToggleName="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_LotType}"
                                        LeftStateText="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_UseExisting}"
                                        RightStateText="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_CreateNew}"
                                        LeftCommand="{Binding ItemLotModel.ToggleExistingCommand}"
                                        RightCommand="{Binding ItemLotModel.ToggleNewCommand}" />

                <!-- Select Lot + New lot fields in the validation container -->
                <StackLayout>

                    <!-- Select Lot picker -->
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0"
                            ColumnSpacing="5"
                            Padding="0"
                            Style="{StaticResource ScannerGridStyle}">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                            </ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="140">
                            </ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                            </RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0"
                                        Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LotLabelStyle}"
                                    Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_LotNumber}">
                            </Label>
                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsNewLotCreating, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}">
                                <StackLayout.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.SelectedLot.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="True" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ValidatableTextInputContainerActive}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.SelectedLot.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="False" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource LotInputContainerStyle}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </StackLayout.Triggers>

                                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource LotPickerStackLayoutStyle}"
                                                AutomationId="ExistingLotInput">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemLotModel.SelectedLot.Value.Identifier}"
                                            Style="{StaticResource LotPickerLabelStyle}">

                                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                            Command="{Binding ShowLotSelectionCommand}"
                                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>

                                    </Label>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>

                            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsNewLotCreating}">
                                <StackLayout.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.NewLot.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="True" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ValidatableTextInputContainerActive}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.NewLot.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="False" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource LotInputContainerStyle}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </StackLayout.Triggers>

                                <!-- New Lot input box -->
                                <Grid RowSpacing="0"
                                        ColumnSpacing="0"
                                        Padding="0"
                                        Style="{StaticResource ScannerGridStyle}">

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*">
                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto">
                                        </ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                                        </RowDefinition>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <controls:TextInput Grid.Column="0"
                                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                                        Style="{StaticResource LotInputStyle}"
                                                        AutomationId="NewLotInput"
                                                        Text="{Binding ItemLotModel.NewLot.Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                                            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Completed"
                                                                                Command="{Binding ItemLotModel.NewLotEnteredCommand}" />
                                            <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                                                                                Command="{Binding ItemLotModel.ValidateNewLotCommand}" />
                                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                                    </controls:TextInput>

                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <!-- Expiration box -->
                        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1"
                                        Grid.Row="0">
                            <Label Style="{StaticResource LotLabelStyle}"
                                    Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_Expiration}">
                            </Label>
                            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource LotInputContainerStyle}">
                                <StackLayout.Triggers>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.ExpirationDate.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="True" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource ValidatableTextInputContainerActive}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                    <MultiTrigger TargetType="StackLayout">
                                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                            <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding ItemLotModel.ExpirationDate.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                                                Value="False" />
                                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Setter Property="Style"
                                                Value="{StaticResource LotInputContainerStyle}" />
                                    </MultiTrigger>
                                </StackLayout.Triggers>

                                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsNewLotCreating}">
                                    <controls:NullableDatePicker Style="{StaticResource LotInputStyle}"
                                                                    NullableDate="{Binding ItemLotModel.ExpirationDate.Value}"
                                                                    AutomationId="NewLotExpirationDateInput"
                                                                    ValueUpdatedCommand="{Binding ItemLotModel.DateSelectedCommand}" >
                                    </controls:NullableDatePicker>
                                </StackLayout>

                                <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsNewLotCreating, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}">
                                    <controls:NullableDatePicker Style="{StaticResource LotInputStyle}"
                                                                    NullableDate="{Binding ItemLotModel.SelectedLot.Value.ExpirationDate}"
                                                                    AutomationId="ExistingLotExpirationDateInput"
                                                                    IsEnabled="False">
                                    </controls:NullableDatePicker>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </StackLayout>

                <!-- Error message box -->
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ErrorMessageContainer}"
                                IsVisible="{Binding ItemLotModel.Errors, Converter={StaticResource ErrorsListToBoolConverter}}"
                                Margin="5">
                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemLotModel.Errors, Converter={StaticResource FirstValidationErrorConverter}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource ErrorMessageLabel}"
                            AutomationId="LoginErrorMessageLabel">
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="6">
                <Image Style="{StaticResource ScannerRoundedCornerStyle}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="7" 
                            Style="{StaticResource BasePageActionButtonRowStyle}" Margin="0,18,0,0"
                            AutomationId="SkipItemButton">
                <Frame Style="{StaticResource BasePageActionButtonFrameStyle}">
                    <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource BasePageActionButtonContainerStyle}">
                        <Label Text="{x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_SaveAndContinue}"
                                Style="{StaticResource BasePageActionButtonLabelStyle}"
                                IsEnabled="{Binding ItemLotModel.IsUpdating, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}" />
                        <Image Style="{StaticResource BasePageContinueButtonImageStyle}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                        Command="{Binding SubmitItemLotCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource BasePageRemainingItemsRowStyle}">
                <Label Text="{Binding Model.CountNumber, StringFormat={x:Static resources:Labels.Receiving_CountName_Template}}"
                        Style="{StaticResource BasePageRemainingItemRowLabelStyle}"
                        AutomationId="CountNumber" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Label Grid.Row="8" x:Name="KeepVisibleLabel" />

        </Grid>
    <!--</ScrollView>-->
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making your view scrollable, the contents obviously don't fit the dimensions of the screen.

Comment: Yes it works when I implement a scrollview but I'd like to avoid doing that if possible. My goal is to shrink the entire layout to make it fit without scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using **Grid** as root layout, we can define the `RowDefinitions` to show proportionally.

For example:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1.2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="10" />
    <RowDefinition Height="0.8*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1.2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1.2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Now above code will show full content even on smaller screen of device.

The `0.8*` means `8%` of screen height, and `1.2*` means `12%` of the screen height. If not above the height of screen , just make their sum less then `10*`.

In addition, we also can use [Xamarin.Forms RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout) to show proportionally no matter the screen of device is large or small.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This looks very promising.

Comment: @Will If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I wasn't able to get around to testing it until now, but this is the solution I was looking for. Marking this as the answer. Thank you very much for the help, JJ!

Comment: @Will Okey, if there are any other problems fell free to update in SO.